# How to send a byte array in a method with OleVariant

Tags: delphi-7, biometrics

How to send a byte array in a method with OleVariant?

This is the method:

```
procedure Import(bInitialize: Integer; nFingerID: Integer; nPurpose: Integer; 
nSrcFPDataType: Integer; nFPDataSize: Integer; FPData1: OleVariant; FPData2: OleVariant); safecall;
```

We've tried to use like this:

```
buftn: array[0..399] of byte;
// fill the buftn array... then
objFPData.Import(1,1,1,400,400,OleVariant(buftn));
```

But it returns the message: "invalid type cast"

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass your `buftn` byte array itself inside of an `OleVariant`. That is not compatible with OLE, which is why you are getting a conversion error.

You have to allocate an OLE-compatible byte array inside the `OleVariant` and then you can copy the bytes into it, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., Variants;

var
  buftn: array[0..399] of Byte;
  v: Variant;
begin
  // fill the buftn array...
  v := VarArrayCreate([Low(buftn), High(buftn)], varByte);
  Move(buftn, VarArrayLock(v)^, sizeof(buftn));
  VarArrayUnlock(v);
  objFPData.Import(1,1,1,400,400,v);
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
uses
  ..., Variants;

var
  buftn: PByte;
  v: Variant;
begin
  v := VarArrayCreate([0, 399], varByte);
  buftn := PByte(VarArrayLock(v));
  // fill the buftn array...
  VarArrayUnlock(v);
  objFPData.Import(1,1,1,400,400,v);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy,
My customer found a solution working like this:
`buftn: array [0..399] of Byte;`
`objFPData.Import(1,0,1,400,400,buftn[0]);`